# Calculate.h file not found in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm just learning how to use Xcode and i'm using a book called "Beginning Max OS X Programming".  I'm working on one of the first exercises. and it told me to save a C file called "Calculate.h" in the same file as main.c and Calculate.c.  Right away, the debugger is giving me an error saying "Calculate.h file not found."

Here's the code for main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Calculate.h>


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int a, b, count, answer;
char op;

// pringt the prompt
printf("Enter an expression: ");

// get the expression
count = scanf("%d %c %d", &a, &op, &b);
if (count !=3) 
{
    printf("bad expression\n");
    return 1;
}

// perform computation
answer = calculate(a, b, op);


// prin the answer
printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", a, op, b, answer);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for Calculate.h:

```
int calculate(int a, int b, char operator);
```

Here is the code for Calculate.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int calculate(int a, int b, char operator)
{
int result;

switch (operator)
{
        case '+':
            result = a + b;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = a - b;
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown operator: %c\n", operator);
            exit(1);
}

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `import "Calculate.h"` (note the "" instead of the <>)